# Querying the embedded map that the key contains "."

Tags: orientdb

I can execute update commands likes below.

```
update #28:51 put sessionStatus = 'session1', true
```

and

```
update #28:51 put sessionStatus = 'session2.s', true
```

This means the key of embedded map can contain dot, and at this point I have the data as below.

[image: The current record]

If the key **does not** contain dot, I can query by following statement.

```
select from gw_true where sessionStatus.session1 = true
```

Please help me the case that key **contains** a dot character.

Comment: Hello, it looks like a bug. Could you please open an issue on github? https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues

Comment: You mean the key in embedded map must not contain "." or something else?